# Lotus Designer - @Trim undone when using sorting

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula, lotus-designer

My application have a table that have 3 columns to be used in View:

[image]

In View, all 10 rows will share a column using `show multiple values as separate entries` and `@Trim`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

I want to sort `Expired By` column in ascending order, but when I did that and refresh my view, it seem to have undone the `@trim`

[image]

Is `@Trim` not compatible with sort functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your "Expired On" column formula to

```
@ToTime(@Trim(
@If(cert != ""; @Text(certend); "") : 
@If(cert_1 != ""; @Text(certend_1); "") : 
@If(cert_2 != ""; @Text(certend_2); "") : 
@If(cert_3 != ""; @Text(certend_3); "") : 
@If(cert_4 != ""; @Text(certend_4); "") : 
@If(cert_5 != ""; @Text(certend_5); "") : 
@If(cert_6 != ""; @Text(certend_6); "") : 
@If(cert_7 != ""; @Text(certend_7); "") : 
@If(cert_8 != ""; @Text(certend_8); "") : 
@If(cert_9 != ""; @Text(certend_9); "")))
```

It adds `certend` values only if related `cert` values are not empty. As you want to sort by this column too you have to use it as DateTime and not as Text type.

Change order of columns. Only the first of the multivalue columns can be sorted. The following multivalue columns have to be unsorted (sort: "none").
[image]

Comment: Originally, for `certend` I didn't use `@text`. It was when the view says `@function: text expected` that I added it in. Anyways now that I switched to this solution, I'm getting the same problem but this time it's saying `@function time/date expected`. Even after adding `@Date` for every `certend` its still giving me the same error.

Comment: You are right. Updated formula.

Comment: At least that solves the `@function` issue. Now the view still have the `@trim` undone when sorting issue. But 10/11/2022 is no longer showing. So that's progress :-)

Comment: Shift column "Expired On" (sorted) to first of the multivalue columns followed by columns "Certificate" (unsorted) and "Certificate No." (unsorted). Only the first of the multivalue columns can be sorted.